# Change PHP GD image output file url name/link

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, gd

I have this problem, i have this script in php that creates a image on the fly, the problem is that the outputted image on the browser is allright, but i need to change it's name.

Ex: **Index.php**

```
<?php $url = "http://www.somesite.com/cls/image_scrc?_aaa=qJ7VgSxWBLG3FfNQVB%2BKI58kfHQulPHZLuLYaZAG6Tk%3D&_ab=3ctGTf547wdsAGjY%2F5FASE%2BpBnbQEAcrhbJzCHQ7mGs%3D&_acb=89e62acf3b4d254abf0c3ab30d6ebb33" ?>

<img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```

The image_scrc.php is the file that creates the image, and as you can see i have several data  that is passed by  the get method.

In the **image_scrc.php**  i have tryed

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
header('Content-Disposition:inline; filename="'.$random_name_jpeg.'"');
```

but the html link is  is always appearing like this

```
http://www.somesite.com/cls/image_scrc?_aaa=qJ7VgSxWBLG3FfNQVB%2BKI58kfHQulPHZLuLYaZAG6Tk%3D&_ab=3ctGTf547wdsAGjY%2F5FASE%2BpBnbQEAcrhbJzCHQ7mGs%3D&_acb=89e62acf3b4d254abf0c3ab30d6ebb33
```

if i select the image on browser and then select copy image link it copies just like this also.

however, when I save the image it assumes the random_name.jpg, but only on save!

i've tried everything, even htaccess rules but nothing seems to work !!

it's this possible to acomplish? transform this

```
http://www.somesite.com/cls/image_scrc?_aaa=qJ7VgSxWBLG3FfNQVB%2BKI58kfHQulPHZLuLYaZAG6Tk%3D&_ab=3ctGTf547wdsAGjY%2F5FASE%2BpBnbQEAcrhbJzCHQ7mGs%3D&_acb=89e62acf3b4d254abf0c3ab30d6ebb33
```

to this

```
http://www.somesite.com/cls/random_name.jpg
```

i cant have the image on the server side! and must be displayed on the fly

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could url_rewrite `anything.jpg` to your php script pretty easily. Then in your `img` tag you just put `<img src='http://www.somesite.com/cls/anything.jpg'>`. If the query string (part after `?`) doesn't change, you could add it to the rewrite or store it in the script. If it does change, you could still just pass the query string to `anything.jpg` if you just add `[QSA]` to the rewrite rule.

Comment: Send the user to example.com/cls/image_scrc.php/random_name.jpg?_aaa=whatever — the script at image_scrc.php will still run, and will still have access to the query string variables, but the browser will save the image as "random_name.jpg".

Comment: save the image in server with the resultant file and redirect the request using header("location:") to the image url

Comment: Ok, the index.php puts on screen several .jpg images that are on the server side,  and this one created by image_scrc.php is the only one that differs. It will become very easy to have a scroller to detect the image that was created by the script. And i'm trying to avoid that. All the other images are some_name.jpg and this is the only one that is not. The get method data is allways diferent. The only way is to create the image to a server folder and then pass the link to the src on the image tag. But the image display's a code and she cant be on the server.
Jonathan, how can i do that ?